# win2go to hard drive possible?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm currently using a win2go drive which has been working fine but is slow. So I'd like to move it now over to my ssd hard drive.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Download [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/)

1) Use it to take a copy of your HDD, it will save it to a image.

2) Write the image to your SSD

[Example videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=clonezilla%20tutorial)